# which is correct here, break or broke?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, orthography, programming

which one is correct?

"Steve was amazing before his leg break."

"Steve was amazing before his leg broke."

Comment: Neither one sounds great. I'd opt for: "...before his leg **got broken**"  OR "...his leg **was broken**".

Answer (score 3):

Either one can be correct.  In the first instance "break" is a noun.

Comment: Though I agree that either could be grammatical, 'leg break' seems unidiomatic appearing only 3 times in the Corpus of Contemporary American English and then only in informal contexts. Not that 'leg broke' referring to the actual human appendage and not a part of an inanimate object is any more common at 5 instances.